# Why does indentation done in vim look different in different editors?

Tags: vim, indentation

I just used vim to edit a javascript file. My indentation in vim is set like so:

[image]
<sub>(source: [take.ms](http://take.ms/XPgNb))</sub>

When I edit a portion of the file, in vim it looks as though the indentation is correct:

[image]
<sub>(source: [take.ms](http://take.ms/hp7kh))</sub>

However, in SourceTree and in Sublime Text, the indentation is incorrect:

**SourceTree:**

[image]
<sub>(source: [take.ms](http://take.ms/ByRLS))</sub>

**Sublime Text:**

[image]

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening and how I might fix it? I'm also curious which, really, is the "true" representation of the file's state.

Comment: One's using tabs, another's using soft-tabs (spaces).

Comment: so what would the solution be?

Answer (score 6):

There are three related settings: `tabstop`, `softtabstop`, and `shiftwidth`. They are *not* the same.

- `tabstop` sets the size of a tab character.
- `softtabstop` sets the number of spaces inserted when the `<Tab>` key is pressed.
- `shiftwidth` sets the number of spaces inserted when autoindentation is used (e.g. after typing `if (foo) {<Cr>`).

If `expandtab` isn't set, then spaces will be automatically replaced by a Tab character (`0x09`) as soon as the number of spaces is a multitude of `tabstop`. If `expandtab` is set, then spaces are never "expanded" to a tab character.

In your case, you only set the `shiftwidth`, which doesn't control the actual size of the tab characters. You either want to set `tabstop` to the same value as Sublime text, or you want to use space indentation by setting `expandtab`. If you use `set list` you can see if your file is using tab characters or spaces (use `set nolist` to disable this).

### Bonus tip

In my personal opinion, you generally want to set all three settings to the same value. I use this command to quickly set all three with `:TS 4`:

```
command! -nargs=1 TS setlocal ts=<args> sts=<args> sw=<args>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution (thanks to @ceejayoz) was to set the `expandtab` option in my `.vimrc` settings, so this:

```
autocmd FileType javascript setlocal shiftwidth=2 tabstop=2 expandtab
autocmd FileType jsx setlocal shiftwidth=2 tabstop=2 expandtab
```

did the job.